# React Dev Tools not updating state

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

I am having a problem with React Dev Tools that has just started happening in the last week. Before that it was working fine. The issue is that the state is not reacting to changes as they occur though they are updating in the "background" (e.g. text entered into an input box is not being registered with standard onChange/handleChange functions. If I click on the "copy to clipboard" button that now appears in the "state" box and paste that into the console, the state is cleary updated. Its just not displaying. Has anyone else encountered this and know of a fix.

I have googled the issue extensively and have only seen recent issues where the entire component display has stopped working. But that is a separate issue. Mine only relates to state updating.

Comment: The exact same thing is happening to me using the Context API and Hooks, the state displayed is not refreshing on its own! If I click somewhere else and click again the ContextProvider it shows the updated value.